# Insert single character string between the values of a tuple (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

Given the example code below (modified from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer)),

```
import collections 
import re

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    keywords = {'IF', 'THEN', 'ENDIF', 'FOR', 'NEXT', 'GOSUB', 'RETURN'}
    token_specification = [
        ('NUMBER',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'), 
        ('ASSIGN',  r':='),          
        ('END',     r';'),          
        ('ID',      r'[A-Za-z]+'),    
        ('OP',      r'[+\-*/]'),     
        ('NEWLINE', r'\n'),          
        ('SKIP',    r'[ \t]+'),       
        ('MISMATCH',r'.'),           
    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        if kind == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = mo.end()
            line_num += 1
        elif kind == 'SKIP':
            pass
        else:
            if kind == 'ID' and value in keywords:
                kind = value
            column = mo.start() - line_start
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)

statements = '''
    IF quantity THEN
        total := total + price * quantity;
        tax := price * 0.05;
    ENDIF; '''

for token in tokenize(statements):
    print(token)
```

I want to be able to insert a single character string (but *not* *hardcode*) between the token values in the `token_specification` and the regex like so:

```
token_specification = [
        ('NUMBER',   'A',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'), 
        ('ASSIGN',   'B',  r':='),          
        ('END',      'C',  r';'),          
        ('ID',       'D',  r'[A-Za-z]+'),    
        ('OP',       'E',  r'[+\-*/]'),     
        ('NEWLINE',  'F',  r'\n'),          
        ('SKIP',     'G',  r'[ \t]+'),       
        ('MISMATCH', 'H',  r'.'), 
]
```

I have considered `ascii_uppercase` but I cannot work the actual syntax of automatically adding that single character in the `token_specification`.
Could someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add this just after you initial `token_specification` declaration:

```
token_specification = [(left, letter, right) for (left, right), letter in zip(token_specification, string.ascii_uppercase)]
```

(as well as an `import string` with your imports)

Comment: Your answer appears so elegant, thanks. However, when I try it exactly as you say I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last): line 46, in <module> for token in tokenize(statements): line 23, in tokenize tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification), line 23, in <genexpr> tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Any ideas? Note that the new `token_specification` is now how I want it regardless of the above error.

Comment: Well I answered your question but did not check the rest of the code. `'(?P<%s>%s)' % pair` is a string formatting operation with 2 placeholders, which worked while each item in `token_specification ` had 2 elements, but fails now that it has 3. Just adapt the format to have a third placeholder (`%s`).

Comment: True. Just wondering if it was in any way related but I will figure it out. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: sorry I posted my previous comment before finishing it. Answer is inside now that I edited it.

Comment: ... or alternatively if you don't need the letter in your regex, just move my suggested line of code after the line starting with `tok_regex = `

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the tuple to list and insert the character in the middle and then convert back to tuple

```
import string 
chars = string.ascii_uppercase 

result = [] 
for i, t in enumerate(token_specification): 
  t_lst = list(t)
  t_lst.insert(1, chars[i])
  result.append(tuple(t_lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

So that you won't run out of letters, start by making an iterator that can produce a letter sequence of letter groupings:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product, imap

# Produce letter groups: A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, ...
charset = [''] + list(ascii_uppercase)
characters = imap(''.join, product(charset, repeat=4))
_ = next(characters)        # Consume initial blank value
```

Next, use [*zip()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) to interlace the letters with the *name* and *pattern* from the *token_specification*:

```
result = [(name, letters, pattern) for (name, pattern), letters
                                   in zip(token_specification, characters)]
```